# Performance profiler for Python

Tags: windows, python, performance-analysis

I am looking for a performance profiler in order to analyze my Python programs.

Requirements:

- works on Windows (Windows 10 at least, Windows 7 would be nice).
- can be commercial.
- at least support sampling (statistical approach).
- ideally support instrumentation (modification of code).
- support for Python 2 and 3. If your tool supports only one version, please mention that, so I can look for another tool for the other version.
- UI for dealing with all the data.
- hierarchical display of where the time is spent.
- focus ("zoom") into a method and rescale it to 100%.

If you know [Jetbrains dotTrace for .NET code](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), then that's roughly what I'm looking for. If you don't know it, here's a small screenshot:

[image: Screenhost of dotTrace in action]

I have tried:

- [looking at this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/44914/tool-for-statistical-performance-measurement-in-production-environments), but it asks "where the interpreter spends the most time". I don't want information about the interpreter, I want information about my code. Also, my question is limited to Windows.

I don't want

- [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) or similar things that I need to insert into my code manually.
- [live-trace](https://github.com/guettli/live-trace) is going into the right direction. I'm looking for something with more GUI.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest starting with pythons own [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) module:

1. No need to change your code in any way when profiling a program
2. Comes with Python (so Free)!
3. Works on Windows, (and  most other platforms).
4. Python 2 & 3

To profile your python program:

```
python -m cProfile -o output_file_name YouProgram.py
```

then put your program through its paces, *(obviously you can add any required parameters at the end of the above line)*. This saves the profile information to the specified filename.

You can then examine the statistics using the [pstats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-pstats) module - this lets you examine the statistics in a python session. Alternatively you can use SnakeViz to view it in a browser or RunSnakeRun profile viewer GUI to view it more comfortably - *the latter runs on python 3.x but should display profiles from python 2 runs with no problem*.

[image: RunSnakeRun]

Comment: That looks good. I'll try it when I'm back in the company on Monday.